SqlBulkCopy - How to force it to use a renamed bcp file
I'm trying to read data from XEL files and input to a SQL Server table.
$bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionString)
$bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.InputXELData"
$bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
$bcp.Dispose()

Our servers has both ASE and MSSQL bcp utilities installed on the same server, so we had to rename the SQL Server bcp as "mssqlbcp".
Now here is the problem, SqlBulkCopy is not working and it is using ASE bcp and no data is been read out of extended event files.
Tested on the server which do not have ASE bcp, and it worked fine.
My question is how can we force SqlBulkCopy to read the "mssqlbcp" rather than ASE "bcp".
Tried looking here but no luck,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8.1
Thanks for your help.

Neither of these utilities are used by SqlBulkCopy. It uses a fast-path TDS message called INSERT BULK and sends it direct to the server. Why it's not working is not clear, but it's not what you think. Where do you get the $dt datatable from? Check what is in the $dt variable, and check your $bcp.ColumnMappings which seems to be missing. Also are you aware of the sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file function?

@Charlieface Thanks for your response. Thanks for clarifying that it is not referring bcp utility internally. As I mentioned, this is working fine on another server where I have not renamed SQL server bcp utility and also not installed ASE bcp. Anyways, will try to troubleshoot further.

Are you getting any error messages?

@HandyD No error messages, it just moves ahead without any action. Tried printing some messages before and after, it prints them and just exits without running bcp in between them.

If there are no errors and no data being loaded into the table, is there anything in the $dt data table? Can you output that variable to the console to confirm there are records in the data table to be loaded?
Also, maybe try an alternative method (check out Write-DbaDbDataTable  in dbatools PowerShell module) to run the bulk copy and see if you get different behaviour.
